# JavaScript Asynchronous Issue

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use the twitter API to get search results and then modify them, before displaying them on the page.

I am new to the idea of Asynchronous functions and I dont see how to run this method for several search strings and work on the results:

```
var results = [];

for (string in searches) {

client.get('search/tweets', {q: searches[string]}, function(error, tweets, response){
   console.log(tweets); // I need to put these in an array (results) and get the next lot
});

}

analyse(results);
```

I need to run search/tweets several times and build up an array of the results so they can be analysed. I dont know how to do this if I have to work in the function? Putting it into a callback function would have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For things like this I like to use Promises. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

```
let promises = [];

// for each string you have create a new promise and put it in an array
for (string in searches) {
    promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        client.get('search/tweets', {q: searches[string]}, function(error, tweets, response){
           resolve(tweets);
        });
    }));
}

// after your loop use Promise.all to wait until all promises are resolved and then do something with the results
Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
    console.log(results); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is this: keep track of how many search terms you are querying, and process the analysis when the last one finishes.

```
var results = [];
var count = 0;

for (s in searches) {

    client.get('search/tweets', {q: searches[string]}, function(error, tweets, response){
       console.log(tweets); 
       results += tweets;
       if (++count == searches.count) analyse(results);
    });

}
```

There are also more "modern" ways of handling async code including [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), which I encourage you to check out in your async endeavours.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two working parts here. 
(1) Running a function on an interval and 
(2) making an async call.

#### Run a function at an interval

The first is the ability to run a function at an interval. This can be accomplished the following way.

```
var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
  // do something here every second
}, 1000);
```

#### Make an Async Call

The second is making an asynchronous call. An asynchronous call is asynchronous because the result cannot be guaranteed to exist at the time of execution. **You must perform any analysis/data manipulation *inside* of the async call.** This is the only way to guarantee a response.

Assuming, based on your example, that `client.get()` is the asynchronous call, you would do something like this:

```
client.get('search/tweets', ..., function(err, tweets, response) {
  // perform some actions on the result
  analyse(tweets);
});
```

---

Putting it all together:

```
// make a request every second
var myInterval = setInterval(function() {

  // perform async operation
  client.get('search/tweets', ..., function(err, tweets, response) {   

    // perform operations on result
    analyse(tweets);
  });

}, 1000);

function analyse(tweets) {
  // do something with data here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're wanting these requests to work in serial(executing one request at a time)... In pure JS, it would go something like:

```
var results=[], i=0, l=searches.length;

var next=function(callback){

    if(i<l)
    {
        client.get("search/tweets", {q:searches[i]}, function(err, tweets, response){

            results.push(tweets);

            next(callback);
        });
    }
    else
    {
        callback(results);   
    }
};

next(function(results){
    analyze(results);
});
```

However, these days, as noted by realseanp, Promises make this way cleaner(although his answer would run the requests in parallel).